# Release application domain from main SWF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, garbage-collection, applicationdomain

i like to know that there is way to remove all data after unload swf .

Calling Loader.unloadAndStop(); remove content and loaded bytes , but loaded classes stays in application domain .

If i load it to separated new ApplicationDomain , gc is going to collect them after unload and remove all references ?

Comment: you're going to an awful lot of trouble to gain at most minimal savings

Comment: I dont think about single bytes , but about classes with lot of graphics or bitmapData inside ( like games stuff , sounds etc. ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, classes you loaded into domain don't stay in memory when unloaded unless you keep references. So, if you did something like:

```
private static var foo:Class = 
    loadedSWF.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("Foo");
```

Then, obviously, it will stay in memory. There are some other things to be aware of, depending on the player version the behavior of `registerClassAlias()` changed in a way that if it was called from the loaded SWF, the alias would be registered in the parent domain, thus there would be no way later to unload the class, unless you register the same alias for another class. In some later, but not the last version, it would properly register classes in the correct domain, but it broke some people's code... *sigh* and today the behavior is sort of unpredictable, it will try to decide what domain is trying to register the alias based on that class uses in that domain, which, of course, may differ at runtime...

Comment: @ wvxvw : "...classes you loaded into domain don't stay in memory when unloaded..."

Even if i load it into ApplicationDomain.currentDomain ?

Comment: Yes , exaclty this what i need to know - other application domain classes can be removed if there is no references , but loaded to current application domain stays .